# how can I animate or transition when data changes in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to animate/transition when the "data" changes.
I tried to wrap h1 tag with transition tag but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <h1>{{data}}</h1>
</transition>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome here. So now that you have this `name="fade"`, you should consider creating the CSS around it: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html